# TreeListControl within each NavbarControl Group

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm very new to WPF and I'm attempting to create a treelist navigation within each navbar group. Because the number of navbar groups and treelists are dynamic I have to make them in code rather than them be pre-defined in XAML.

I have tested the following so far which is meant to define the navbar group's content rather than use the default item

```
private void CreateGroup2(NavBarControl navBar)
{
    NavBarGroup group2 = new NavBarGroup();
    group2.Header = "Custom Content";
    //Specify that the group's content should be defined via the Content property
    group2.DisplaySource = DisplaySource.Content;

    TreeListControl tree = new TreeListControl();
    tree.ItemsSource = TreeList_DataBinding.Stuff.GetStuff();
    group2.Content = tree;


    navBar.Groups.Add(group2);
}
```

This gives an Exception: Grid.InfiniteGridSizeException: By default, an infinite grid height is not allowed since all grid rows will be rendered and hence the grid will work very slowly. To fix this issue, you should place the grid into a container that will give a finite height to the grid, or you should manually specify the grid's Height or MaxHeight. Note that you can also avoid this exception by setting the TreeListControl.AllowInfiniteGridSize static property to True, but in that case the grid will run slowly.

I'm a little confused as I'm not using a grid? Can anyone give any pointers what's wrong and how I can add a treview under each navbar group?

Thank You

Comment: If you didn't yet buy devexpress, use telerik ;) And in cases when you have dynamic data, consider to use MVVM pattern http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278901/MVVM-Pattern-Made-Simple

Comment: My client wants a specific WPF template in DX and already has the license so there's no movement on that unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels a bit wrong answering my own question but I managed to get it working using the following

```
private void CreateGroup2(NavBarGroup navBarGroup)
{

    System.Windows.Controls.TreeView treeview = new System.Windows.Controls.TreeView();

    TreeViewItem nod = new TreeViewItem();
    nod.Header = "Tree Node1";
    treeview.Items.Add(nod);

    TreeViewItem nod1 = new TreeViewItem();
    nod1.Header = "Tree Node2";
    treeview.Items.Add(nod1);

    TreeViewItem nod2 = new TreeViewItem();
    nod2.Header = "Tree Node3";
    nod1.Items.Add(nod2);

    //StackPanel stcPnl = new StackPanel(); /optiona
    //stcPnl.Children.Add(treeview);
    //navBarGroup.Content = stcPnl;

    navBarGroup.Content = treeview;

    navBarGroup.DisplaySource = DisplaySource.Content;

}
```

Comment: You are actually encouraged to answer your own questions.  You can even accept the answer too, adding to your own reputation on the site!